# php - take a value by any parameter and any method

Tags: php, parameters, execution

I'm trying to make a simple page command execution vulnerability... This is my code:

```
system($_GET['cmd']);
```

It is working fine, like this : http://example/index.php?cmd=ls

The problem is I want make this little code to work with any parameter and any method (GET or POST)

For example, if any parameter is used then it will still pass through the system method, ie: "?hello=ls". (I did not know they where to use `hello` as the key. Any ideas?

Comment: use `$_REQUEST` then

Answer (score 0):

You could store each index key in an array then loop the set value.

```
$keys = ['cmd', 'hello', 'etc..']; // jus add your params

// GET params
foreach($keys as $_key) {
    if(isset($_GET[$_key]) && !empty($_GET[$_key])) {
        system($_GET[$_key]);
    }
}

// POST params
foreach($keys as $_key) {
    if(isset($_POST[$_key]) && !empty($_POST[$_key])) {
        system($_POST[$_key]);
    }
}
```

If you do not want to know the key to the POST/GET then:

```
foreach($_GET as $key) {
    system($_GET[$key]);
}

foreach($_POST as $key) {
    system($_POST[$key]);
}
```

Comment: OP: *"the problem is i want make this little code, work with any parameter and any method (GET or POST)"*

Comment: you mean that i cant do that ?

Comment: Ofc you can and its an easy method just some people like to cry a lot

Comment: i dont want define specific params.. i want work with anything.

Comment: then just foreach `$_GET` and foreach `$_POST` and it will go through each of anything set (no matter what the key is called)... see updated question for solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use: 
`file_get_contents('php://input');` to get RAW input